# Urls with escaped double quotes at the end break ngSanitize

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm using messages from Twitter in an Angular project. I'm using linky to present urls in tweets as clickable links. My problem is that when a double quote is used immediately after a url in a link, ngSanitize, which parses the urls, causes an error.

This message causes no problems:

> "text":"RT @SPORTBILD: .@GaryLineker lobt das @DFB_Team in höchsten
>   Tönen! Und er sagt: \"Dankeschön!\" Video: https://t.co/zwWWa7LpvD
>   \n#SportBildAwa…"

This message causes an error:

> "text":"RT @NUFC_1980_1994: \"@turnipheadpic: Quayside Market 1986 c/o
>   Newcastle Libraries http://t.co/b8MueTjx9I\" #nufc #safc"

Error message:

```
Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the
following block of html: <a target="_blank"
href="http://t.co/b8MueTjx9I"">http://t.co/b8MueTjx9I&#34;</a> #nufc
#safc
```

As you can tell, the escaped double quote isn't being handled correctly by ngSanitize. It's considered part of the url, and parsing breaks down.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't so hard in the end. I found the following git issue: [Linky on emails breaks with double quote in 1.2.21](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8520)

So I just updated the packages, angular and angular-sanitize to 1.2.3, now the bug doesn't happen any more!